# Unable to create array of inner class

Tags: java, arrays, inner-classes

I am a beginner in java. I want to create array of inner class in class other than outer class. But I can't as compiler shows error '(' expected.
Help.

```
Tree test = new Tree();
Tree.Node[] A = test.new Node[10];
```

error

```
Tree.java:72: error: '(' expected
Tree.Node[] A = test.new Node[10];
                         ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an array you don't create instances of the element type, you just create an array containing `null` references, so you create it as you would any array (regardless of the element type being an inner class):

```
Tree.Node[] A = new Tree.Node[10];
```

When you initialize an element of the array, you create an instance of the inner class, which requires an enclosing class instance:

```
A[0] = test.new Node ();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code-line:

```
Tree.Node[] A = test.new Node[10];
```

is invalid, you are maybe confused with the syntax for creating an instance only

```
Tree.Node fooA = test.new Node();
```

what you are looking to do must be written as:

```
Tree.Node[] A = new Tree.Node[10];
```

that is the correct way to declare an array of inner classes in java